# Local temp variables for methods with modern ES6 javascript classes

Tags: javascript, es6-class, iife

In old-style javascript classes you can use [IIFE](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6) to define some temporary variables for methods, which are pre-allocated and thus does not have to call `new` every invocation of the method.

```
// constructor
var MyClass = function(x,y,z){ this.pos=new vec3(x,y,z); } 

// method
MyClass.prototype.vec_combine = ( function( a,b,c, up,fw) {
    var side = new vec3(); // allocated at construction, not at invocation
    return function vec_combine( a,b,c, up,fw) { 
       cross_product( up,fw, side ); // side is perpendicular to up,fw
       side.normalize();
       this.pos.x = fw.x*a + up.x*b + side.x*c;
       this.pos.y = fw.y*a + up.y*b + side.y*c;
       this.pos.z = fw.z*a + up.z*b + side.z*c; 
    }
}() );
```

How you can do it with modern ES6 like classes?

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(x,y,z){ this.pos=new vec3(x,y,z); } 

  // method
  vec_combine( a,b,c, up,fw) {
    var side = new vec3(); // I don't want do "new" each invocation
    cross_product( up,fw, side ); // side is perpendicular to up,fw
    side.normalize();
       this.pos.x = fw.x*a + up.x*b + side.x*c;
       this.pos.y = fw.y*a + up.y*b + side.y*c;
       this.pos.z = fw.z*a + up.z*b + side.z*c; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not make `side` a class variable on construction? `this.side = new vec3()`

Comment: First of all, nothing stops you from using your upper way in ES6. What i personally would do is use typescript and place it as `private static readonly`. If you don't use typscript, you won't have `private` and if you don't already use ESNext also no `readonly` (though it can be done with proper descriptor changes).

Comment: Just a small update: Apparently all of it is still at best in the proposal/draft/candidate stage, so unless you use typescript i don't think this works properly (as in easier to read and write than other suggested solutions). I forgot you [can't even write fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) in vanilla JS yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it as you have requested.

However, if you are already using ES6, you're likely using modules. You may as well just have a variable in the module that is not exported.

```
// Not exported
var side = new vec3(); // I don't want do "new" each invocation

export class MyClass{
  constructor(x,y,z){ this.pos=new vec3(x,y,z); } 

  // method
  vec_combine( a,b,c, up,fw) {
    cross_product( up,fw, side ); // side is perpendicular to up,fw
    side.normalize();
    this.pos.x = fw.x*a + up.x*b + side.x*c;
    this.pos.y = fw.y*a + up.y*b + side.y*c;
    this.pos.z = fw.z*a + up.z*b + side.z*c; 
  }
}
```

If you are not using modules, you could put the entire class in an IIFE

```
const MyClass =  (() => {
  var side = new vec3(); // I don't want do "new" each invocation

  return class {
    constructor(x,y,z){ this.pos=new vec3(x,y,z); } 

    vec_combine( a,b,c, up,fw) {
      cross_product( up,fw, side ); // side is perpendicular to up,fw
      side.normalize();
      this.pos.x = fw.x*a + up.x*b + side.x*c;
      this.pos.y = fw.y*a + up.y*b + side.y*c;
      this.pos.z = fw.z*a + up.z*b + side.z*c; 
    }
  }
```

});

Comment: nice thing about IIFE is that definition of temp variable is local, which makes the code much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't. You have to fall back to setting the prototype:

```
class Test { }

Test.prototype.test  = (s => () => console.log(s))("hi");

new Test().test()
```

To beautify this a bit, you could rewrite the methods with a small helper:

```
const init = (cl, name, ...args) => cl.prototype[name] = cl.prototype[name](...args);
```

Usable as:

```
class Test {
 test(s) {
   return function() {
     console.log(s);
   }
 }
}

init(Test, "test", "hi");
new Test().test();
```

---

However in most cases it should be sufficient to scope the variable locally to the whole class:

```
const Test = (s => {
   return class {
     test(){ console.log(s); }
   };
})("hi");
```

Or:

```
let Test;
{
   const s = "hi";

   Test = class {
      test() { console.log(s);
   };
}
```

... Or you just put it in the upper scope and hope everyone follows the "dont use underscore variables" rule:

```
const _s = "hi";

class Test {
  test() { console.log(_s); }
}
```